# HTTPS and Secured Websockets clarification

Tags: https, websocket

We have a web application that is required to run on HTTPS. We started to use a third party control that uses Websockets to connect to a windows service that will be running on the user computer. [This page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications#Security_considerations#Security_considerations) states that websockets should not be used in a mixed content environment. Is this security consideration still applies in this case (the websocket connection is not trying to connect to the same server that handled the https request)? If so, why would a websockets to a localhost would need to be secured? Isn't this just added complexity for no reason?

Comment: I think the question implied is "is the localhost network secure?"... which has many different answers. I think the answer I loved most was "when the localhost network is breached, you have bigger issues than data encryption". But maybe it's because I'm lazy.

Comment: @Myst my question is specifically regarding weather the secure websocket is  required or no ? (when trying to connecting cross domain to a localhost).

Comment: Since it is not the web page itself making the connection using the browser's native WebSocket API, but rather is a 3rd party control (presumably) using its own WebSocket implementation, I think the issue would  be moot as this would fall under Section 10.1 "Non-Browser Clients" of [RFC 6455](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455) of the WebSocket spec.